# How to create Models in Rails and pass data from models to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to rails. I have created controller and able to see changes in http://127.0.0.1:3000/.

How to create Models in Rails and pass data from models to controller.

Comment: I suggest you to follow this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: Please read at least one documentation about rails. This question would have been answered there for you: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Answer (score 2):

If you need to access a controller variable from a model it generally means your design is wrong because a controller serves as bridge between view and model (at least in Rails), controller gets info from models, models shouldn't know anything about controllers, but if you want to do it anyway.
For your first question you can simply create models in rails as
rails g model MODELNAME 
g as short of generate